# Organizar dados tabela HTML - CSS - SQL

Tags: html, mysql, css

Tenho o seguinte código

```html
<table border="1">
<?php
$sql = $mysql->prepare("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE status = 0");
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($id);
$sql->store_result();
if($sql->num_rows() == 0){
 echo "<tr><td>Sem registros</td></tr>";
} else {
 while ($sql->fetch()) { 
  echo "<tr>
  <td>" . $id . "</td>
  </tr>";
 }
}
?>
</table>
```

O qual me retorna 30 registros alinhados de cima a baixo, da seguinte maneira:

[image: pagina_1]

Preciso ordenar os resultados de forma crescente, porém organizado em outras colunas, de forma que fique assim:

[image: pagina_2]

Como proceder neste caso?

Comment: Um link que talvez possa te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608513/loop-to-populate-html-table-vertically

Comment: Com CSS e a propriedade "column-count" vc consegue montar essa estrutura tranquilamente.

Comment: Olá amigo. Conseguiu resolver? veja que postei uma solução usando JavaScript, mas alguém achou inútil e votou negativo. Se não conseguiu resolver, podemos ver uma solução usando apenas PHP. É só me dar um retorno aí. Obg!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha sugestão é usar JavaScript para alterar a estrutura, inserindo as células nas devidas linhas. No PHP você pode inserir classes numerando as linhas em sequência, de 1 a 10. A estrutura da tabela ficaria como mostra a imagem abaixo, cada linha numa sequência de `linha1` a `linha10`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A partir disso, com JavaScript eu posso juntar todas as células das linhas com a mesma classe. Basta você inserir um script logo após o código PHP que constrói a tabela:

```
<?php
$sql = $mysql->prepare("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE status = 0");
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($id);
$sql->store_result();
if($sql->num_rows() == 0){
    echo "<tr><td>Sem registros</td></tr>";
} else {
   $conta = 1; // inicia variável com valor 1
    while ($sql->fetch()) { 

      if($conta%11 == 0){ // reseta $conta a cada 11 linhas
         $conta = 1;
      }

      $classe = "linha".$conta;

        echo "<tr class=". $classe ."> // insere a classe na TR
        <td>" . $id . "</td>
        </tr>";

      $conta++;

    }
}
?>
</table>

<script>
var linhas = document.body.querySelectorAll("tr[class*='linha']"); //seleciona todas as linhas da tabela
for(var x=10; x<linhas.length; x++){ // loop a partir da 11ª linha
   var cls = linhas[x].className.match(/\d+/)[0]; // pega o número da linha
   document.querySelector(".linha"+cls).innerHTML += linhas[x].innerHTML; // insere a TD na respectiva linha
   linhas[x].outerHTML = ''; // remove a linha
}
</script>
```

O resultado será o que mostra a figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]